# Issue accessing a variable in a Java class

Tags: java, android

I am trying to access the variable ArrayofTaxiDrivers in the class DownloadTask from the onCreate method of my activity file. However the variable is blank when accessed this way. The content does show when accessed from within the onPostExecute method of DownloadTask though.

Any help is greatly appreciated!

```
public class DownloadTask extends AsyncTask<String,Void,String> {

        ArrayList<TaxiDriver> ArrayofTaxiDrivers = new ArrayList<TaxiDriver>();

        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(String... urls) {
          String result = "";
          URL url;
          HttpURLConnection urlConnection = null;

          try {

            url = new URL(urls[0]);
            urlConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
            InputStream in = urlConnection.getInputStream();
            InputStreamReader reader = new InputStreamReader(in);
            int data = reader.read();

            while (data != -1) {
                char current = (char) data;
                result += current;
                data = reader.read();
            }

            return result;

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            return null;
        }
      }
        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String s) {
            super.onPostExecute(s);
            try {
                JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(s);
                JSONArray items = jsonObject.getJSONArray("items");
                DownloadTask task = new DownloadTask();
                for(int i=0; i<items.length(); i++) {
                    JSONObject itemsObject = items.getJSONObject(i);
                    JSONObject fields = itemsObject.getJSONObject("fields");

                    task.addTaxiDriver(new TaxiDriver(fields.getString("name"), fields.getString("contact")));(asList(fields.getString("name"), fields.getString("contact"))));
                }
                Log.i("info",task.ArrayofTaxiDrivers.toString());
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

}

protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_taxi_main);

        DownloadTask task = new DownloadTask();
        task.execute("https://test.com/json");

        Log.i("info",task.ArrayofTaxiDrivers.toString());
}
```

Comment: Show your doInBackground

Comment: Added doinBackground

Comment: You could just move the `ArrayList<TaxiDriver> ArrayofTaxiDrivers = new ArrayList<TaxiDriver>();` on the `Activity/Fragment` class, or use getters and setters on the `AsyncTask` instance.

Comment: Yes, You need to pass arrayOfTaxiDriver as a parameter to AsynTask or getter setter would be fine too

Comment: it has to do with  lifecycle, when you create activity, you have empty array, hence when you call your log, hence your variable is empty
thn you create your task which obtain data and populate them to your array. hence when you log value on post execute value is populated

Answer (score 0):

When you call 
`task.execute("https://test.com/json");`
the task will be executed based on its priority. For this reason the onPostExecute will be called after some time and probably after the onCreate

```
Log.i("info",task.ArrayofTaxiDrivers.toString());
```

I suggest you to think that "execute" is an instruction that exits immediatly and only after a while it will be executed.

Answer (score 0):

> I am trying to access the variable ArrayofTaxiDrivers in the class
>   DownloadTask from the `onCreate` method of my `Activity`.

That is because when you created `DownloadTask`, the `List` `ArryofTaxiDrivers` is initialized and at that time the size of the `List` is zero.

If you have the data in the `onPostExecute()` method, that means it was probably added by `AsyncTask`'s `doInBackground()` method. Could be somewhere else entirely depending on your code.

Now the `AsyncTask` works asynchronously: it means that while it has been kicked to start executing, it doesn't start right away. However it will eventually start executing.

So when you access the list in `onCreate()` of the `Activity`, the list doesn't have any data because you haven't added to it.

**What you should do**

Instead implement an `interface`/`callback` to notify the `Activity` that the data is loaded and ready to be used. This callback can come from `onPostExecute()`.

Comment: Thank you for the clear explanation. Will do as you suggest.

Comment: @AbubakkerMoallim can you explain how?

Comment: The answer is you cant use variable declared inside asynctask outside its scope. so If you want to use it throughout your fragment/activity you need to pass it inside DownloadTask constructor and set it

Comment: @Abbas what you said is 100% correct but it does not match his case because he is trying to access something which is declared inside asyntask and the global is not set inside asynctask

Comment: @AbubakkerMoallim I see your point... Are you sure the `AsyncTask` and `Activity` are not in the same package? `ArrayofTaxiDrivers` is declared as package private which means it *can* be acceessed from any class in the **same package**. I think they are, besides if they were not the OP wouldn't have said the list is '*blank*'.

Comment: Being in the same package the access of `ArrayofTaxiDrivers` is well within scope.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/195257/discussion-between-abubakker-moallim-and-abbas).